# Ankhsvn "Failed to authorize"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, repository, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I am trying to set up Ankhsvn 2.1.7444.278 with Subversion 1.5.0 on both VS08 and VS2010.B2.

When supplying Ankhsvn with repository url, it recognises the url and allow me to select my repository. The repository is empty (since I haven't put anything into it yet). When I click OK and after applying a log-entry, it return with the error "You failed to authorize against the remote repository.".

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Casper

Comment: Log in manually first (Tortoise). I suspect your certificate or something expired.

Comment: Where are you supplying the repository url? Where are you clicking OK?

Comment: @Sander: When I right click on my solution in VS, I can access a subversion item, which opens a new window. Here I can supply Ankhsvn with the repository url and afterwards click OK.

@Leppie, Sander: Thanks for your quick replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem.

Using TortoiseSVN, I tried to commit a file and I got another error telling me that the database was locked. The problem was that I didn't have the correct user rights to access the repository. By this I mean that I wasn't added as a user on the repository folder on the server and I added myself using Windows Explorer and not through various credentials in the Subversion, the Tortoise client or Ankhsvn - as suggested in other forums.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem but with a different cause. I didn't uncommented the `password-db = passwd` line in `svnserve.conf` using svnserve -d -r [path to repositories]. Also, be sure to set a password in the `passwd` file as well.

Comment: Thanks! According to the SVN docs, I exported the repo, and imported the repo and I expected the conf directory to be part of the export but I was wrong. I had to copy the conf directory from the original repo to the new repo and HUP the service then the SVN check in worked as it did before.